# Django filters options specific to queryset only

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) to provide user filtering on a list view on my site, e.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit)
    price = models.CharField(...)
    release_date = models.DateTimeField(...)

class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['fruit', 'price', 'release_date']

def my_banana_orange_view(request):
   ...
   queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(fruit__name__in=['banana', 'orange'])
   filter = Filter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)

   return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'queryset': queryset, 'filter': filter})
```

Now if I do this, I can display just the `MyModel` entries that have either banana or orange relationships, but `MyFilter` will still give the option of all the fruits in the `Fruit` model. I'm trying to find a setting for a FilterSet to just show options related to the input queryset, but can't find one. Does one exist?

Otherwise I guess I would have to override the filter to do something like this:

```
class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.filters['fruit'].extra['queryset'] = Fruit.objects.filter(mymodel=self.queryset)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['fruit', 'price', 'release_date']
```

Which seems a bit overkill. Only showing options based on the input queryset seems like desirable behaviour, but I can't find any documentation for it. Is there a good way to do this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first param for`FilterSet` is `data`, the second is `queryset`.

Try something along the lines of `filter = MyFilter(data=request.GET, queryset=queryset)` in your view.

See: http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/usage.html#the-view

Comment: OK I missed out the request info from my example. Doing this still gives me all entries in the `Fruit` model in the dropdown though, not just the ones that are in the queryset...